# Google cloud functions - delete old versions of the functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I deployed some functions on google cloud using firebase functions. I know the versioning happens on source code for each deployment. Is it possible to delete the old versions except the active one?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, specifically?

Comment: @DougStevenson no problem, just want to delete the history of the old deployments

Comment: some confidential info has been exposed in the old versions

Comment: @DougStevenson, is there anyway to tell Google how many versions to keep? the bucket which firebase stores all versions files grows fast as hell and i would like to clean old versions or just keep the 5 more recent or something... is it possible to do?

Comment: 18 months and no changes from google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete a version from a function using Google Console.

When you deploy a function you will see that they print the `sourceUploadUrl` that contains the bucket where your function is stored, but you don't have access to that bucket.

My function is deployed in Europe, so the source upload url looks like this

```
sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-europe-west1-(random-numbers)/(random-numbers).zip?......
```

So they create a special bucket for my function, but I don't have access to it.

You can delete the function and then redeploy it or contact support and maybe they will remove the source code

Comment: That's what i did today. I deleted all functions and redeployed again.